# Form in Access VBA using Function to set Field from the Network ID

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been tinkering with the code below for a while. Been trying to figure out how to have it set the User ID based on the Owner field which is based on a function grabbing the persons network ID. This is done

The problem I keep running into is that I keep getting a Type Mismatch error on the If statement line. I should also mention this is being done as a checkbox from forms.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
Dim c As MSForms.Control
Dim StrSQL As String

For Each c In Me.Controls
   If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
    If c Then
     Select Case c.Name
        Case "CheckBox1"
            'Monday
            Hide
            CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [Need Help], [DateCreated], [Owner]) VALUES ('Change Notice', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),2)) mod 7,Date()), 'No', Date(), '" & Getowner() & "')")
            GetUser
    Case Else
        End Select
       End If
      End If
    Next c
End Sub

Function GetOwner()
  GetOwner = Environ("USERNAME")   
End Function

Function GetUser()
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTasks")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTasks")

rs2.MoveLast
With rs2
  If Environ("USERNAME") = "12345" Then
    .Edit
    ![User ID] = "Name"
    .Update
  End If
End With

rs1.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs1 = Nothing 'Clean up
rs2.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs2 = Nothing 'Clean up

Forms![frmTasks].Form.Requery
Forms![frmTasks].Form.Refresh
End Function
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've updated the code and now it's recognizing the user but getting an Object required error on line `[User ID] = "Name"` I've tried to add the object by using `"Forms.Tasks.[User ID]"` but it doesn't recognize the field even though it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Had to use recordset in order to get it to work.

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
Dim c As MSForms.Control
Dim StrSQL As String

For Each c In Me.Controls
   If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
    If c Then
     Select Case c.Name
        Case "CheckBox1"
            'Monday
            Hide
            CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [Need Help], [DateCreated], [Owner]) VALUES ('Change Notice', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),2)) mod 7,Date()), 'No', Date(), '" & Getowner() & "')")
            GetUser
    Case Else
        End Select
       End If
      End If
    Next c
End Sub

Function GetOwner()
  GetOwner = Environ("USERNAME")   
End Function

Function GetUser()
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTasks")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTasks")

rs2.MoveLast
With rs2
  If Environ("USERNAME") = "12345" Then
    .Edit
    ![User ID] = "Name"
    .Update
  End If
End With

rs1.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs1 = Nothing 'Clean up
rs2.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs2 = Nothing 'Clean up

Forms![frmTasks].Form.Requery
Forms![frmTasks].Form.Refresh
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an old bug, that you couldn't just expect a checkbox's value (its default property) to behave as a boolean.

So try:

```vb
    If c.Value = True Then
```

Also, you missed a quote here:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblTasks ([Task Name], [Task Description], [Company], [Priority], [Status], [DueDate], [User ID], [Need Help], [DateCreated], [Owner]) VALUES ('Change Notice', 'Daily Task', '(4) Ginny''s', '(1) Hot!', '0', DateAdd('d',(8-Weekday(Date(),2)) mod 7, Date()), " & GetUser() & ", 'No', Date(), '" & GetOwner() & "')")
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tips and the catch! Still getting type mismatch on the same line. I'm wondering if it's cause the Owner field is string and User ID field isn't? But I'm not sure why it would care since I'm not having it enter a string in the User ID field. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If `[User ID]` is numeric, remove the quotes (see edited answer, please). Also, if `[Need Help]` is a boolean, replace `'No'` with `False`.

Comment: User ID is text, Owner is String and I'm not using boolean for Need Help it's just a yes/no selection box. I guess I could change it but it seemed like a minor thing right now.

Comment: I'm getting closer. No longer getting the Type Mis match error and it's creating the record but it's still not filling the User ID field. It's coming up blank now.

Comment: Then, I guess, GetUserId returns nothing.